# libuv how to ignore SIGPIPE when connection reset by peer (linux)

Tags: sockets, libuv

I receive a `SIGPIPE` from `uv_write()` as connection is reset by the peer.

```
p/x stream->flags
0x46064

./src/unix/internal.h:# define UV__POLLRDHUP 0x2000
```

For BSD to prevent `SIGPIPE` libuv has:

```
./src/unix/core.c

#if defined(SO_NOSIGPIPE)
 {
    int on = 1;
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, &on, sizeof(on));
 }
#endif
```

Linux does not have `SO_NOSIGPIPE` as an option. Any suggestions how to handle `SIGPIPE` signal for linux other than `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);`

Comment: `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);` is the simplest solution,IMHO. (and you'll have to handle the errno==EPIPE cases on failing system calls)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to update `uv_write()` to call [`send()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) with the `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag:

> Don't generate a `SIGPIPE` signal if the peer on a stream-oriented socket has closed the connection.  The `EPIPE` error is still returned.  This provides similar behavior to using [`sigaction(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) to ignore `SIGPIPE`, but, whereas `MSG_NOSIGNAL` is a per-call feature, ignoring `SIGPIPE` sets a process attribute that affects all threads in the process.

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/issues/1254): _The reason libuv doesn't use MSG_NOSIGNAL is that sendmsg() is a much more expensive system call than write(). [...]_

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is: no, any way to handle `SIGPIPE` but to set a signal handler.

See [this issue](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/issues/1254) for a discussion about `SO_NOSIGPIPE` and `libuv`. It also clarifies why there exists that code for BSD.